# Stop a process for human control if some score is reached (Screening System)

Tags: design-patterns, software, architectural-patterns, business-rules

Say I have a blogging system.  Users can create posts that will get automatically published unless some score is reached.

So when users save a post, we do some calculations and add up some numbers to score it.  
Below is an example of how I have this working:

```
$post->hasTooManySwearWords() // adds 3 to the score
$post->postIsLongerThan100Words() // adds 1 to the score
$post->author->hasPostedMoreThan5TimesThisMonth() adds 5, which means immediately stop
```

The system comes up with some threshold (say 4 for example). If the score is equal to or above 4, then the post won't get auto published and a human must review it.

The problem I have now is that the threshold feels arbitrary. And adding rules is a ball ache cause you have to make sure they play nice with other rules. The maths gets tricky. Is there a better way to design this?

***Note:*** this question is in reality for a financial system where transactions get stopped if they have some threshold score. Just didn't want to put sensitive details here.

Comment: From a software engineering point of view, blocking financial transactions is "implement algorithm from data science team". I'd be very concerned that a naive threshold algorithm based on a few features would cause more harm than good.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKendall, Are there some generally accepted algorithms for this, someone had suggested something about Bayesian filters? Thanks.

Comment: The scoring system that you propose looks very similar to the filtering done by spam filters.

Comment: Pretty similar. So I was also thinking one way to enhance the current threshold system is to have different levels. Like a Like `Level1=1, Level2=2, Level3=3, Level4=5`. Threshold=5. So a `Level4` failure is always a blocking `5*Level1` is a blocking failure, etc. Just some ideas that came to mind. Bleh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this sort of system is far too complex to be designed based on a Stack Overflow discussion. It could very easily become an absolute horror in several ways:

1. The broad strokes could be very easy to brute force by someone using a shill account, at which point criminals could figure out which measures they need to take to work around them reliably - amounts, delays between transactions, recipients, and so on.
2. The system would have to be incredibly flexible to avoid effectively blacklisting entire groups of customers - refugees sending money back to their families, people serving debt on another continent, gamers doing microtransactions, former inmates buying ammonium chloride to make candy, vacationers paying for their one big holiday, you name it. When the computer says no, this could have long-lasting repercussions well beyond the two individuals sending and receiving money.
3. The rules and interactions between them could become very complex to maintain, to the point where only the maintainers (or not even they) would understand how to tweak them without making the situation worse. At which point the system ossifies, which will probably lead to the problems above.

That said, there are two general approaches for such systems already mentioned:

1. A Bayesian filter, which you could train with existing known good and bad transactions. This is probably one of the best known ways of classifying things, but there's an important reason I believe they will not perform as reliably as spam filters do: the lower the percentage of bad transactions, the harder it is to classify them correctly. In other words, given a finite training set, you will get a *lot* of false negatives and positives if bad transactions are sufficiently rare. I don't have the numbers, but I believe it's easy to calculate just how many people you'll inconvenience for every genuinely "bad" transaction you block, and conversely how many "bad" transactions you approve. Another reason this may not perform very well is that I don't believe Bayesian filters take time into account - each transaction would be considered completely independent of each other.
2. The SpamAssassin way of specifying many, **many** business rules and weighting for each of them as you mentioned. An easy way of defining a threshold for such a rule set would be to sum up the weights for each of them and take a percentage of that.

I do hope for the customers' sake that if such a system gets implemented there are always going to be **humans with the power to decide in the loop** - can you imagine being stuck not being able to pay for something important until someone tweaks the rules?

Comment: Thanks for that. Thanks for taking the time. Will look at both approaches and see what fits best.

Comment: I like your provocative introduction "far too complex to be designed based on a Stack Overflow discussion" immediately followed by a lot of ideas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Financial systems usually stop transactions for review, based on some risk assessment. And so do blog post filtering systems.

A very simple approach is to identify broad categories of related risks.  Here a very simplified example:

```
Blog system                         Financial system
---------------------------         -----------------------------------
1.Risk of loosing readers             Risk of loosing money 
   1.1 spammer                            - market losses
   1.2 offensive content                  - fraud
   1.3 boring content
2.Risk of being sued                  Regulatory risk
```

You would then have scores per category.  You could then design a very simple rule system, that just goes through all the rules.  New rule are just added to the set. But instead of having an arbitrary single score that spoils it all, the rule would update the scores in the relevant categories:

```
                Risk components          1.1   1.2  1.3   2.
post->hasOneFrequentlyUsedSwearWord()           1
post->hasTooManySwearWords()                    2
post->hasRacistTerms()                          5         10
post->isLongerThan100Words()                         2
post->hasManyRedundantTerms()                        3
author->howManyPostsThisMonth()           5
```

This lets you analyse more easily how rules interact. But the biggest advantage of this separation of concerns is that you can define the decision making process independently of the individual rules and decide how to best combine the scores. You can use several approaches in the same time, for example:

- Combine some related scores such as 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 (e.g. just adding the sub-scores, weighting them if needed, or taking the max of the 3 values) but not 2.
- Have different scales for different risk categories (for financial loss, you would certainly calculate the potential amount of loss).
- Use different thresholds for different categories.  You could for example be risk adverse and stop every post that causes a risk to be sued, but be more permissive on the boredom axe, because it's more subjective.
- Decide not to stop because of a very low score in one of the categories (in a financial system, you wouldn't stop for a transaction of very low value, because the human intervention would be more expensive than the loss).

Of course, it's not as sophisticated as Baysian filters, genetic algorithms or neural nets. But even if it's not the most advance approach, it's very flexible and a good start compared to your current one dimensional scoring.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have now is that the threshold feels arbitrary.

As you decided on this threshold, that is the exact semantical definition of "arbitrary".

But what other option is there, other than an arbitrary threshold? The only other way I can think of is that you initially calculate scores but do not automatically block the blog post yet. Have the blogging be moderated by humans (who, for the sake of the example, precisely uphold the rules).

After a while, you can look at your generated data. Most notably, focus on the relationship between **calculcated score and ban percentage**.

This may reveal lots of things that you initially did not expect. I'm just inventing findings to prove the point:

- Every post that hits score 4 or more always gets banned. This strongly suggests that your threshold shouldn't be higher than 4.
- No post with a score lower than 12 was ever banned. This strongly suggests that your threshold should never be lower than 12.
- There is no meaningful correlation to be found between the calculated score and whether the post was banned or not. This strongy suggests that your point calculation is flawed and not actually accounting for the proper things.

---

We can't really answer it here. There are many avenues to pursue here:

- Only automoderate what is strictly forbidden. Human moderate everything else (this is effectively what StackExchange does).
- Implement machine learning so you don't have to figure out the right rules for point calculation, and instead have a machine do it for you.
- Do not rely on the current automatic banning because being *correct* is more important than being automated.
- Rely on the current automatic banning because being *automated* is more important than never making a mistake.
- ...